# How to select rows between two date with next and previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table with following structure

```
ID  PersonID    Date
---------------------------
1   1           2017-04-01
2   1           2017-04-15
3   1           2017-05-13
4   1           2017-06-15
5   1           2017-08-13
6   1           2017-10-02
7   2           2017-05-04
8   2           2017-09-16
9   3           2017-04-23
10  3           2017-07-06
11  4           2017-06-01
```

I want to `Select` rows between `2017-05-01` and `2017-08-26` and for each `PersonID` Next and Previous rows if exists.

I want this result:

```
ID  PersonID    Date
------------------------------
2   1           2017-04-15
3   1           2017-05-13
4   1           2017-06-15
5   1           2017-08-13
6   1           2017-10-02
7   2           2017-05-04
8   2           2017-09-16
9   3           2017-04-23
10  3           2017-07-06
11  4           2017-06-01
```

Comment: Then select it? There are tons of examples

Comment: i don't see any rows for that matches the date range that you specified. How do you get that result ?

Comment: i can select like this `select * from table1 where date between '2017-05-01' and '2017-08-26'` . but how can get next and previous rows?

Comment: use `UNION ALL` and select the top 1 before the first date and after the last date (`ORDER BY Date DESC` for the one before and `ORDER BY Date` for the one after, of course).

Comment: i want result for each PersonID

Comment: Then do that the standard way... e.g. `... union all select columns from (select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by personid order by date desc) from mytable where date < somedate) as t where rn = 1 union all...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following query

```
create table TestData(ID int,PersonID int,[Date] date)

insert TestData(ID,PersonID,[Date])values
(1 ,1,'20170401'),(2 ,1,'20170415'),(3 ,1,'20170513'),
(4 ,1,'20170615'),(5 ,1,'20170813'),(6 ,1,'20171002'),
(7 ,2,'20170504'),(8 ,2,'20170916'),(9 ,3,'20170423'),
(10,3,'20170706'),(11,4,'20170601')
----------------
DECLARE
  @FromDate date='20170501',
  @ToDate date='20170826'

SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      LAG(IIF([Date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate,1,0))OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY [Date],ID) LagOK,
      LEAD(IIF([Date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate,1,0))OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY [Date],ID) LeadOK
    FROM TestData
  ) q
WHERE ([Date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate OR LagOK=1 OR LeadOK=1)
```

A variant with `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER`

```
;WITH numCTE AS(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY [Date],ID) N
  FROM TestData
)
SELECT n.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT PersonID,MIN(N)-1 MinN,MAX(N)+1 MaxN
    FROM numCTE
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    GROUP BY PersonID
  ) q
JOIN numCTE n on n.PersonID=q.PersonID AND n.N BETWEEN q.MinN AND q.MaxN
```

I've added new test data and modified queries for this case, too

```
create table TestData(ID int,PersonID int,[Date] date)

insert TestData(ID,PersonID,[Date])values
(1 ,1,'20170401'),(2 ,1,'20170415'),(3 ,1,'20170513'),
(4 ,1,'20170615'),(5 ,1,'20170813'),(6 ,1,'20171002'),
(7 ,2,'20170504'),(8 ,2,'20170916'),(9 ,3,'20170423'),
(10,3,'20170706'),(11,4,'20170601'),
(14,6,'20170415'),(15,6,'20170913'),(16,6,'20171015') -- new test data

DECLARE
  @FromDate date='20170501',
  @ToDate date='20170826'

SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *,
      LAG(IIF([Date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate,1,0))OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY [Date],ID) LagOK,
      LEAD(IIF([Date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate,1,0))OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY [Date],ID) LeadOK
    FROM
      (
        SELECT ID,PersonID,[Date]
        FROM TestData

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DISTINCT NULL,PersonID,@FromDate -- add phantom rows for some people
        FROM TestData p
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TestData d WHERE d.[Date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND d.PersonID=p.PersonID)
      ) q
  ) q
WHERE ([Date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate OR LagOK=1 OR LeadOK=1)
  AND ID IS NOT NULL -- exclude phantom rows from result
```

And a new variant with CTE and ROW_NUMBER

```
;WITH numCTE AS(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY [Date],ID) N
  FROM
    (
      SELECT ID,PersonID,[Date]
      FROM TestData

      UNION ALL

      SELECT DISTINCT NULL,PersonID,@FromDate -- add phantom rows for some people
      FROM TestData p
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TestData d WHERE d.[Date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate AND d.PersonID=p.PersonID)
    ) q
)
SELECT n.*
FROM
  (
    SELECT PersonID,MIN(N)-1 MinN,MAX(N)+1 MaxN
    FROM numCTE
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    GROUP BY PersonID
  ) q
JOIN numCTE n on n.PersonID=q.PersonID AND n.N BETWEEN q.MinN AND q.MaxN
WHERE ID IS NOT NULL -- exclude phantom rows from result
```

Comment: your code now work for this test

      `14   6           2017-04-15 - 
      15   6           2017-09-13 - 
      16   6           2017-10-15`

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do this as:

```
select id, personid, date
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by personid) as prev_date,
             lead(date) over (partition by personid) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where (date >= '2017-05-01' and date <= '2017-08-26') or
      (prev_date >= '2017-05-01' and prev_date <= '2017-08-26') or
      (next_date >= '2017-05-01' and next_date <= '2017-08-26');
```

The logic is simple:  You are looking for either the date, the previous date, or the next date being in the interval that you specify.